# Python - How to schedule ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm using a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` with a `Queue`, the code is something like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from queue import Queue

def func(parent):
    return parent//2, parent//2, parent<=2

def worker(parent, q):
    child1, child2, end = func(parent)
    print(parent) 
    if not end:
        q.put(child1)
        q.put(child2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    q.put(100)
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6)
    while True:
        parent = q.get()
        future = executor.submit(worker, parent, q)
        if q.empty() and future.done():
            break
```

The problem with this code is that the `future.done()` is never True, and I cannot get out of this infinite `while` loop.

My expected outcome is to wait until there's nothing to process. i.e. the queue is empty, and all worker have done their job, nothing further shall be put into this queue. Then I can stop this loop and do sth else.

P.S. the actual `func` I'm using is more complex than the above example, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not patient enough: The call to `executor.submit` returns immediately, even if the implied call to `worker` hasn't happened -- that is exactly the point of asynchronous constructs like futures. So when you check `future.done()` directly afterwards, there is a good chance that this check is performed before the executor had time to execute `worker`, meaning that your future won't be done, yet.

You can verify this by inserting the following code between the call to `submit` and your `if` statement:

```
import time
time.sleep(0.1)
```

This does achieve what you're looking for, but it doesn't really solve your problem in an elegant way.

Looking deeper, you're problem is that your scheduled tasks may generate new tasks, and that you only know whether they did so when they have completed. This means you have to wait until the task you just scheduled has executed before you can decide whether to stop scheduling new tasks:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    q.put(100)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        while not q.empty():
            parent = q.get()
            future = executor.submit(worker, parent, q)
            future.result()  # Wait for task
```

Also make sure to call `Executor.shutdown`, or better to use the executor in a context manager (as shown above) so that all resources are freed correctly once you're done.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want